# Ruby SOAP 1.9 Fails on Self-Signed Servers

Tags: ruby, soap, ruby-1.9.3

I'm porting a piece of code from Ruby 1.8.7 to Ruby 1.9.3 that acts as a SOAP client. The client talks to a server that uses a self-signed certificate (on the same machine in this case), but whenever I perform a SOAP call, it fails with an `OpenSSL::SSL:SSLError`:

```
/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:303:
in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B:
certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

I've tried installing soap4r via gem (which I then [had to hack](http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=41231) to get it to require correctly). I've also tried installing the spox repo version as other SO questions suggest:

```
mkdir -pv ${APPSCALE_HOME}/downloads
cd ${APPSCALE_HOME}/downloads
git clone https://github.com/spox/soap4r-spox.git
cd soap4r-spox
ruby setup.rb all
cd ..
rm -rf soap4r-spox
```

Which also fails with the same issue. I'm on Ubuntu Precise, so I've tried installing Ruby 1.9.3 via apt and via RVM, which also have the same problem. Finally, since I have RVM, I also tried using Ruby 2.0.0, which also has the same issue.

I can connect to other sites (e.g., google, rubygems) fine, so it doesn't look like the same problem that I've seen other report about their certs being in a place where Ruby can't see it. Any ideas? Of course, the code that I'm using is (truncated for readability):

```
require 'openssl'
require 'soap/rpc/driver'

class UserAppClient
  attr_reader :conn, :ip, :secret


  # The port that the UserAppServer binds to, by default.
  SERVER_PORT = 4343


  def initialize(ip, secret)
    @ip = ip
    @secret = secret

    @conn = SOAP::RPC::Driver.new("https://#{@ip}:#{SERVER_PORT}")
    @conn.add_method("get_all_apps", "secret")
  end

  def get_all_apps(retry_on_except=true)
    all_apps = @conn.get_all_apps(@secret)
    app_list = all_apps.split(":")
    app_list = app_list - [app_list[0]] # first item is a dummy value
    return app_list
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you really work at google?